# BlueJ Postgresql driver not found

Tags: java, bluej

I have created a java application which I would like to connect to a database, below is a snippet of my code

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
String host = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost";
String user = "user";
String password = "password";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, password);
```

I get the error below when trying to run the application

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

I am new to the SQL element of Java, I know java programming very well but not the SQL side.

I am using BlueJ to create my program and it seems it cannot find the driver for Postgresql, what am I doing wrong? I am new this and only today just trying to create a test program to get a better understanding of how it works and need help with how to get the driver working.

Added the driver files from the Postgres website to BlueJ via the method in the comments, restarted BlueJ, the drivers say they are loaded but still get an error saying:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with "SQL". Setup your classpath correctly and you should be fine.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how do i do that? I haven't come across this error before, and how do you setup the classpath?

Comment: Sorry I don't use BlueJ. Look for something where you add a jar file to your project definition (= classpath). A quick search in the internet turns up: http://www.bluej.org/help/archive.html#tip5

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name theres nothing like that in bluej itself, but when I navigate to the area the application was installed, and in that folder there are jar files, what do I do? Do I copy a file in there? Where do i get the jar file from?

Comment: added tag so this may be found more easily by people who actually know bluej.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added the driver files from the postgres website, I restarted BlueJ and the drivers are loaded now, but when I run the application i still get an error saying that no suitable driver found, do i have to change this section? Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")

Comment: BlueJ is a teaching tool and is not a good option for general development. I recommend learning how to run it directly from the command line (e.g. java -cp .;postgres.jar MyProgram), then switch to a "real" IDE once you understand how the JVM works.